# How to link a php drop-down menu to other php and show mysql data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two php file (player.php & team.php). First, i want to build a drop down menu in team.php and show each option in form of "TeamID: teamName". Then, when I click the SUBMIT button, it will direct me to the player.php and show me the player whose belong to the team I chose.

Here is the sample mySQL data:

```
Teams                     
teamID        teamName           
   1          CLE                       
   2          BOS
   3          GSW

playerDetail  
teamID       playerName    playerID 
   1              LBJ         23
   1              Wade        9

echo "<form action='team.php' method='GET'>";
echo "<select name='teamID'>";
$query = "SELECT * FROM Teams;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die( "Unable to execute query:".mysql_error());

while($rowB = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<option value='".$rowB['teamID']."'>";
    echo "".$rowB['teamID'].":".$rowB['teamname']."";
    echo "</option>";
}
echo "<input type='submit'>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";
```

What should I add so that the page can be directed from team.php to player.php

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Simply change `action="team.php"` to `action="player.php"`.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you do form validation in `header.php` you would do all of that and then use `header('Location: player.php');` to redirect the browser to your player page.  You can use session variables to pass whatever data you need to `player.php`.

However, if you do the form validation in `player.php`, just change your `<form action="team.php"...` to `<form action="player.php"...`